# openssl extension is missing (Composer installation openSUSE)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-openssl

After i downloaded the composer installer file from the composer website
i tried to install it using command :

```
 ~> php installer
```

Output :

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

I modified the `php.ini` file  and delet the `;` front of  `extension=php_openssl.dll` 
and then i restarted my `apache2` serever but it still the same error message .

Comment: DLLs are for windows

Comment: @miken32 i installed php5-openssl and it work perfectly ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved.

Try In command

```
$ zypper install php5-openssl
```